# WinError 10049 when trying to connect to receive messages from multicast IP

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have a bunch of devices that send messages using mDNS. i want to receive those messages. but the code always fails with `OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

```
import struct
import socket

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.0.251'
MCAST_PORT = 5353
IS_ALL_GROUPS = False

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
if IS_ALL_GROUPS:
    # on this port, receives ALL multicast groups
    sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
else:
    # on this port, listen ONLY to MCAST_GRP
    sock.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))

mreq = struct.pack("4sL", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while endLoop == 0:
# For Python 3, change next line to "print(sock.recv(10240))"
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(10240)
    print(f"Received message from {addr}:\n {data}")
```

I tried closing every application that uses the port, but that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you have to add membership before bind?

Comment: also gives me the samer error

Comment: Why are you listening on a multicast address? You have to listen to a local ip, not a group of ips, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Skip the if/else and just do the true part. Don’t bind to the mcast ip

Answer (score 0):

The IP and port you bind to is local, not external. You cannot bind to a multicast because that would be binding to multiple ips, most of which are probably not your local machine. Instead, you have to bind to a local port. I do not think there is a way to check if an ip is part of a multicast group, but I don’t understand what you are trying to do anyway. I recommend you change to
`sock.bind((‘0.0.0.0’, MCAST_PORT))`